# Is it possible to add new tracks to a playing playlist in spotify?

Tags: spotify

I'm trying to understand as much functionality of the libspotify examples as possible. But I don't know how the tracks/playlists are synchronized.

I used "jukebox" example to play a playlist with 5 tracks. At the same time, I used "spshell" example to add a new track to the playlist with the index different from the current playing track. "spshell" shows the track is added successfully. But "jukebox" does not play the new track even after being restarted. Did I miss something?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, post some examples that show where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it can take a little while before the playlist is synced to the backend. A good way to debug this is to have the playlist open in the Spotify client at the same time you're using spshell - you can log into Spotify with the same account from as many places as you like - only playback is limited to one application at a time.

If spshell isn't picking up the new track in the playlist in the next launch, let it sit a little while to sync with the playlist service before viewing/playing the tracks.

Playlist sync is normally pretty fast, but sometimes the playlist system gets put under heavy load and it can take a little while.

Comment: I can see the playlist is updated very fast either in Linux using "spshell" program or in Windows with Spotify Client. But when I play the playlist, the newly added track is not played. It only shows "1 tracks were added" but doesn't really play that new track. Are you saying it's because the playlist system has heavy load and takes time?

Comment: one more question - the "playtrack" program started to play a track very fast two days ago and started very slow today (few minutes). And the "jukebox" starts to play tracks pretty fast, but doesn't quit when all the tracks are completed playing. What could be the reason?

Comment: Your best bet is to look at the code in playtrack and jukebox to see how they work.

Comment: To my understand, there is no way for users to control when the call back functions are called. So for "playtrack" example, it takes few minutes to start playing a track - I can see the program is sitting there waiting for metadata_updated() to be called. But this program starts playing a track immediately few days ago. That's why I don't understand.

Comment: Correct — the callbacks are called when libSpotify receives information from the backend, so obviously they aren't controllable by the user. It looks like the metadata service is being slow at the moment.

Comment: Is the metadata service same for "jukebox" program and "playtrack" program? metadata_updated() of "jukebox" is called immediately after "jukebox" program starts, but metadata_updated() of "playtrack" starts few minutes after "playtrack" program starts.

Comment: Yes. The "service" refers to the Spotify backend. metadata_updated() can and will be called many, many times during an application's lifetime.

Comment: …but don't get hung up on how the sample apps work - waiting for the callback may not be needed. Write your own application and you'll understand how it works a lot better.

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to write my own. One more question - Is it true that a track can be played only if its metadata is loaded?

Comment: Just try it out — if it can't be played, you'll get an error code explaining why.

Comment: Well, I tried. It always give me the error SP_ERROR_IS_LOADING. Looks like all I can do is to wait.